# Some Kafka producers that are transactional others that are not

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We use StreamListeners for Spring-Kafka, and send messages using a JPA based outbox. The outbox is emptied async from consumption, so we do not want transactions on the "read from JPA table, produce message to Kafka".

But we also have retry topics, so if consumption fails, we will move the failed message to a retry topic (in the end a DLT), and this we do need to be transactional.

As far as I can see it is only possible the turn on/off transactions for producers on a global basis (setting the transaction-id-prefix), and not on the concrete bindings, making i.e. 'output1' transactional and 'output2' non-transactional, but I could be mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are talking about spring-cloud-stream - I have added those tags to your question.

To support this, you should define two Kafka binders, one transactional and one not and then specify which binder to use for each output.

Similar to when you want to talk to different clusters:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-systems